# Counting character in string in Haskell

Tags: string, haskell, count, character

```
string = "this is an example string"
```

in haskell, how can i count how many times the character 'a' appears in the string above? Preferably in one line.

Comment: What are your thoughts or attempts on how to do this?

Comment: Did you try out what was suggested in the [helpful comment straight under your previous, strongly related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29035559/haskell-count-words-and-chars-within-a-string#comment46311923_29035559) yet? If not, go do that first before asking another question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows no independent effort.

Answer (score 1):

Think about it this way: you want to know the size of the list in which all letters that are not 'a' have been removed. To remove these, we can use `filter`.  This function filters out any items in a list that do not satisfy a given predicate.  Then getting the size of this list is trivial with `length`.

```
length $ filter (\x -> x=='a') "this is an example string"
```

Edit:
As per [AndrewC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1598537/andrewc)'s suggestion, you can also write this as:

```
length $ filter (=='a') "this is an example string"
```

This way is more readable and clearer.

Comment: `(\x -> x=='a')` can be written `(=='a')`.

Comment: Thanks, I always miss that.